# Populate a Nested Mongoose Object w/ a Nested Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Working on my first project and have been stumped on this for a couple days.

I'm trying to populate an object that contains the brewery info and the single corresponding beer from the Beer model.

models.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var beerSchema = Schema({
    breweryName: String,
    beer: [{
        beerName: String
    }]
});

var draftlistSchema = Schema ({
    userName: String,
    tap: [{
        tapNo: Number,
        _tapBeer: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Beer' },
        tapStatus: String
    }]
});

var Draftlist = mongoose.model('Draftlist', draftlistSchema);
var Beer = mongoose.model('Beer', beerSchema);

module.exports = {
    Draftlist: Draftlist,
    Beer: Beer
    }
```

route.js

```
var getDraftlist = function(user, callback) {
  models.Draftlist.findOne({ 'userName': user }).populate( {
    path: 'tap._tapBeer',
    model: 'Draftlist'
    }).exec(function(err, draftlist) {
    // console.log(draftlist.tap)
    console.log(draftlist);
    callback(draftlist);      
  });
};`
```

I'm getting a null returned with the current code. Ideally I would like the returned object to look something like--

```
{
breweryName: Some Brewery,
beer: {// Beer object that was referenced by Id //}
}
```

Draftlist Object w/ null return

```
{ _id: 590bd0615a190204fca6d467,
  userName: 'A New User1',
  __v: 1,
  tap: 
   [ { tapNo: 1,
       _tapBeer: null,
       tapStatus: 'onTap',
       _id: 590bd0615a190204fca6d46d },
     { tapNo: 2,
       _tapBeer: null,
       tapStatus: 'onTap',
       _id: 590bd0615a190204fca6d46c },
     { tapNo: 3,
       _tapBeer: null,
       tapStatus: 'onTap',
       _id: 590bd0615a190204fca6d46b },
     { tapNo: null,
       _tapBeer: null,
       tapStatus: 'Cellar',
       _id: 590bd0615a190204fca6d46a },
     { tapNo: null,
       _tapBeer: null,
       tapStatus: 'Cellar',
       _id: 590bd0615a190204fca6d469 },
     { tapNo: null,
       _tapBeer: null,
       tapStatus: 'Cellar',
       _id: 590bd0615a190204fca6d468 },
     { _tapBeer: null,
       tapStatus: 'Cellar',
       _id: 590bd0735a190204fca6d470 } ] }
```

Beer Object

```
{ breweryName: 'Beachwood',
  _id: 590bd3f1ed13510514405cba,
  beer: [ { beerName: 'IPA', _id: 590bd3f1ed13510514405cbb } ] }
```

Comment: Have you tried ? `populate( {
    path: 'tap._tapBeer',
    model: 'Beer'
    } )` or just `.populate('tap._tapBeer')`

Comment: @Veeram read carefully, he already uses it (:

Comment: @num8er he was referencing the wrong model.

Comment: my mistake, seems like it's late night in my place (:

Comment: @veeram I tried that and its still returning a null

Comment: Try adding `mongoose.set('debug', true);` at the top of the file and check the queries on the console and can you add a sample document from both of your collections ?

Comment: debug returned 'Mongoose: draftlists.findOne({ userName: 'A New User1' }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: beers.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5903d1b51894381cca103c92"), ObjectId("590bd0735a190204fca6d46f"), ObjectId("590bd3f1ed13510514405cbb"), ObjectId("590bd832b1d1ed0545d25fba") ] } }, { fields: {} })'

Comment: In the above I see that mongoose is searching beers, but I need it to be beers.beer.find({})

Comment: it's eager loading, it's normal, it takes all bears that needed in previous request and then merges according ids

Answer (score 0):

Use [mongoose-deep-populate](https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate)

```
const
 mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const 
  BeerSchema = Schema({
    breweryName: Schema.Types.String,
    beer: [{
      beerName: Schema.Types.String
    }]
  }),
  DraftlistSchema = Schema ({
    userName: Schema.Types.String,
    tap: [{
        tapNo: Schema.Types.Number,
        _tapBeer: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
          ref: 'Beer' 
        },
        tapStatus: Schema.Types.String
    }]
  });

DraftlistSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);

var Draftlist = mongoose.model('Draftlist', DraftlistSchema);
var Beer = mongoose.model('Beer', BeerSchema);

module.exports = {Draftlist, Beer};
```

usage:

```
const getDraftlist = (userName, callback) => {
  models
    .Draftlist
      .findOne({
       userName
      })
      .deepPopulate('tap._tapBeer')
      .exec((err, draftlist) => {
        console.log(draftlist);
        callback(draftlist);      
      });
};
```

or:

```
const Draftlist = models.Draftlist;
const getDraftlist = (userName, callback) => {
  Draftlist
    .findOne({
     userName
    })
    .exec((err, draftlist) => {
      Draftlist
        .deepPopulate(
          draftlist, 'tap._tapBeer', 
          (err, draflist) => {
            console.log(draftlist);
            callback(draftlist);  
          });
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks but this is still returning a null. I think this is because I'm referencing the ID of the beer objects nested in the BeerSchema. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are You sure that You've documents in Your collections that references correctly?

Comment: @BHalvy82 also try another example in my answer

Comment: Tried the other example and still no luck. I'm positive that the ObjectId's match up.